# Cordova inappbrowser facebook login white screen

Tags: facebook, cordova, inappbrowser

I have been trying to login to my Cordova project using inappbrowser and web app facebook javascript sdk its working fine on the native browser but when using Inappbrowser it gets stuck on a white screen and freezes there... has anyone else came across this issue as well? Inappbrowser version 1.2.1

Many thanks

Comment: finally do you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have the same issue and i am using version 1.3.0

I think its due to the Facebook redirect uri, When i login or share from
inappbrowser Facebook processes the request and the only way is to hit the 
back button.

current versions

PGB CLI 5.2.0
IAB 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to fix it I removed all plugins and add again, since my project was running in an old version of phonegap.

Are you testing in ios ?

If so, another configuration that I did is in the .plist of project for the keys "NSAppTransportSecurity" and "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" (true)

Here is my .plist:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"         "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
      <dict>
        ...
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        ...
        <dict>
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
          <true/>
          ...
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </plist>
```